# Bioacoustics Example Questions from Area51

Tags: discussion, questions

I see that none of our questions from Area51 (https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics?phase=definition&tab=votes#tab-top) are transferred to the Beta site. Should each author transfer their question manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right, they are not transferred automatically. This can be done only manually. Users are supposed to create quality questions from the proposals on Area 51.

Technically any user of Bioacoustics can transfer any of the proposals. Some users may not feel it is right if someone else uses their proposal. It is probably best to wait if some good proposals are left neglected.

The most important is to:

- Create high quality questions.
- Create welcoming atmosphere and not discourage fellow users.

Comment: I don't agree. Those questions aren't necessarily supoosed to go on the main site, and we have to be clear that users should not steal other people's questions.

Comment: @NikeDattani I did not write that they all should be transferred and I wrote "**Technically** any user ... can ..." --- You can try to put a recommendation here on meta that only the original author of the question should transfer it here. I do not feel it is right to make some strictly limiting recommendation. Certainly after certain time passes no one should be frowned upon for transferring a neglected question. --- The other answer by anonymous2 is certainly more detailed. I think that one should be accepted instead of mine :)

Comment: @NikeDattani I improved my answer.

Answer (score 8):

The fact is that the questions no the definition portion of area51 are not full fleshed out questions. They are ideas of questions which could be asked on the site; essentially, the idea is to make sure that the subject of the proposed site is condusive to a wide enough range of topics that the site will run smoothly and produce lots of good content.

Once the site enters private beta, you can (if you want) take questions from there and ask them here.  Bear in mind that as I mentionned before they will need more fleshing out: what have you looked up so far? What are some details regarding your specific question?